# Data Factory triggers two releases on Azure DevOps after Pull Request

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, azure-data-factory, pull-request, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a continuous integration of Data Factory with Azure DevOps and after making any changes to the Data Factory pipeline, we make a pull request so that this change is sent to production. However, after the pull request, two releases are automatically created in Azure DevOps and only one should be created. I searched for changes in Azure DevOps but I only find changes for CI and we don't have a CI pipeline in Azure DevOps.
In Azure DevOps, I defined the continuous deployment trigger for the specific branch that is used in production and still generates two releases in the same branch.
Could you please guide us with settings?
Thank you all.

Tests on other branches;
Releases executed manually in Azure DevOps do not generate two new releases;
We cloned the Data Factory Trigger without success.

Comment: Are you using old school releases rather than pure YAML release pipelines? You get a lot more control with YAML pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps has the 20-MB REST API limit. When the ARM template exceeds this size, ADF internally splits the template file into multiple files with linked templates to solve this issue. As a side effect, this split could result in customer's triggers being run more than once.

To resolve this issue, you can use ADF **Automated publish** (preferred) or **manual trigger** method to trigger once instead of twice or more.

You can see this info on the official doc [Troubleshoot CI-CD, Azure DevOps, and GitHub issues in Azure Data Factory and Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/ci-cd-github-troubleshoot-guide#devops-api-limit-of-20-mb-causes-adf-trigger-twice-or-more-instead-of-once).

---

Update

If your release pipeline has both **Continuous deployment trigger** and **Pull request trigger** enabled, two releases will also be triggered when the Branch filters of CD trigger is the same as the Target Branch Filters of PR trigger. If so, you can disable the PR trigger or change the branch filters.

[image]